# SSL not working when accessing site without www in front of URL

Tags: apache, ssl, certbot

Ok, so accessing my site through www.luvifermente.eu, https://www.luvifermente.eu and just luvifermente.eu works as intended.

But if I access it with https://luvifermente.eu, firefox is giving me the full screen ssl warning.

I'm using apache2 on ubuntu 18.04, and I use certbot to issue the certificates.

I tried to change this through the rewrite engine, but to no avail.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =https://luvifermente.eu
RewriteRule ^ www.luvifermente.eu [END,NE,R=permanent]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.luvifermente.eu [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =luvifermente.eu [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =https://luvifermente.eu
RewriteRule ^ https://www.luvifermente.eu%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

I have no idea how to proceed. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your certificate have Common Name bind to www.luvifermente.eu. Issue new certificate with both host names you want to use.